# Clipping in WEBGL fragment shader according primitive vertices

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

I am new to WEBGL, I read a lot of posts about fragment shaders. However, I cannot figure out how to access the primitive vertices (or a flag for each vertex) in the fragment shader.

My goal is to discard the fragment if at least one of its primitive vertices are clipped.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly access vertices in a fragment shader. The only data a fragment shader gets by default is the screen coordinate (canvas/framebuffer coord) and depth buffer value for the current pixel being rasterized. All other data you have to pass in.

Of the top of my head, in the vertex shader you could compute if a vertex is clipped and pass that info on to the fragment shaders as a varying. You'd pass 0 if not clipped and 1 if clipped. varyings get interpolated so if in the fragment shader the varying is > 0 then one of the vertices was clipped.

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
varying float clipped;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  clipped = (
      any(lessThan(gl_Position.xyz, -gl_Position.www)) ||
      any(greaterThan(gl_Position.xyz, gl_Position.www))
    ) ? 1.0
      : 0.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
varying float clipped;
void main() {
  if (clipped > 0.0) {
    discard;
  }
  gl_FragColor = gl_FrontFacing ? vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) : vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each of
// position, normals, texcoord, indices of a sphere.
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 8, 8);

function render(time) {
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer for each attribute
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, prgInfo, bufferInfo);

  gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);

  const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5.0;
  const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  m4.translate(mat, [
      Math.sin(time / 1200), 
      Math.sin(time / 1300), 
      Math.sin(time / 1400) - 1.8,
  ], mat);
  m4.rotateX(mat, time / 1000, mat);
  m4.rotateY(mat, time / 1100, mat);

  // calls gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
    matrix: mat, 
  });

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

There are probably more efficient ways like pass all vertices of a triangle to the vertex shader and if any one of them is clipped set all vertices to be clipped so that triangle is not even rasterized.

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 position1;  // second vertex for triangle
attribute vec4 position2;  // third vertex for triangle
uniform mat4 matrix;

bool vertexClipped(vec4 clipspace) {
  return any(lessThan(clipspace.xyz, -clipspace.www)) ||
         any(greaterThan(clipspace.xyz, clipspace.www));
}

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  vec4 clipPosition1 = matrix * position1;
  vec4 clipPosition2 = matrix * position2;
  
  bool clipped = vertexClipped(gl_Position) ||
                 vertexClipped(clipPosition1) ||
                 vertexClipped(clipPosition2);
                 
  if (clipped) {
     gl_Position = vec4(vec3(2), 1); // some offscreen value
  }
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = gl_FrontFacing ? vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) : vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const verts = twgl.primitives.deindexVertices(twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 8, 8));
// copy the positions
const position1 = new Float32Array(verts.position);
const position2 = new Float32Array(verts.position);
// shift the positions so we can pass all 3 vertices for each triangle
// to the vertex shader for each iteration
for (let i = 0; i < position1.length; i += 9) {
  { 
     // 0, 1, 2 => 1, 2, 0
     const temp = position1.slice(i, i + 3);
     position1.set(position1.slice(i + 3, i + 9), i);
     position1.set(temp, i + 6);
  }
  {
     // 0, 1, 2 => 2, 0, 1
     const temp = position2.slice(i + 6, i + 9);
     position2.set(position2.slice(i + 0, i + 6), i + 3);
     position2.set(temp, i);
  }  
}
verts.position1 = position1;
verts.position2 = position2;

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each of
// position, normals, texcoord, indices of a sphere.
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, verts);

function render(time) {
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer for each attribute
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, prgInfo, bufferInfo);

  gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);

  const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5.0;
  const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  m4.translate(mat, [
      Math.sin(time / 1200), 
      Math.sin(time / 1300), 
      Math.sin(time / 1400) - 1.8,
  ], mat);
  m4.rotateX(mat, time / 1000, mat);
  m4.rotateY(mat, time / 1100, mat);

  // calls gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
    matrix: mat, 
  });

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

This would arguably be more efficient since instead of rejecting 1000s of pixels one at a time we're rejecting the entire triangle and skipping even checking per pixel. It takes more data though since we need to be able to pass in all 3 vertices for every triangle to the vertex shader at the same time.

note: if you're new to WebGL you might find [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) useful.